# Flutter: Inside Drawer move ListTile Items to Bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment

Inside the 2nd Container where the Text Account and Logout is located, i'd like that this is at the Bottom of the Drawer. I Added the Widget Align and alignment:bottomCenter, but this doesn't work. I also tried is with FractionalOffset but this doesn't work aswell.

What mistake am i making here that the Container is not moved to the Bottom?

**Code**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/models/global.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/screens/meal_plan/meal_plan.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/screens/shopping_plan/shopping.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/bloc/auth/auth_bloc.dart';
import 'package:mealapp/bloc/auth/auth_event.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.white,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
      statusBarIconBrightness: Brightness.dark,
    ));
    final authBloc = context.bloc<AuthBloc>();

    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        drawer: Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(canvasColor: darkGreyColor),
          child: Drawer(
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              children: <Widget>[
                DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Settings',
                      style: darkTodoTitle,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                ListTile(
                  leading:
                      Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.white, size: 25),
                  onTap: () {},
                  title: Text(
                    'Create New List',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 1.8,
                                color: Colors.white54,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,
                            color: Colors.white, size: 25),
                        onTap: () {},
                        title: Text(
                          'Here the Lists you got access or created',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                 child: Align(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Expanded(
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                              child: Container(
                                height: 1.8,
                                color: Colors.white54,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,
                            color: Colors.white, size: 25),
                        onTap: () {},
                        title: Text(
                          'Account',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListTile(
                        leading:
                            Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.white, size: 25),
                        onTap: () => authBloc.add(LogoutUser()),
                        title: Text(
                          'Logout',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        appBar: AppBar(
          brightness: Brightness.light,
          elevation: 0,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (context) => IconButton(
                onPressed: () => _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer(),
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                )),
          ),
          title: TabBar(
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.fastfood),
              ),
              Tab(
                icon: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),
              ),
            ],
            labelColor: darkGreyColor,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.blue,
            indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
            indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            indicatorColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            MealPage(),
            ShoppingPage(),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you'd need to use a column instead of a listview. But I'm also just curious to know, it seems you have plans to have more list tiles under the 'Here the Lists you got access or created' list tile? Because in that case, if you're going to have a dynamic number of tiles, you'd have to account for what happens those tiles take up more space than the height of the drawer.

Comment: Yeah i want to have more Lists inside it. I think that with the ListView it is a Scrollable List so i thing that would not be that issue.

I tried wrapping the ListView inside a Column but that didn't worked aswell.

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap `ListTile` Widget inside `Align` Widget and provide `alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter` . This `Align` Widget should be wrapped with `Expanded` Widget as you mentioned in the question you missed to wrap `Align` inside `Expanded` Widget. Try as follows this will help you.

```
Expanded(
    child: Align(
         alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
         child: ListTile(
             leading: Icon(Icons.account_box,
             color: Colors.white, size: 25),
             onTap: () {},
                 title: Text(
                 'Account',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20
                  ),
              ),
          ),
      ),
),
```